# How to delete block of text hidden in file from GitHub?

Tags: html, css, github

I'm recreating [this project](https://github.com/skolo-online/ai-content-starting-template) for my own use. It generates a webpage using [this template](https://github.com/skolo-online/ai-content-starting-template/blob/main/templates/includes/layout.html). The webpage renders as the image below:
[image: current display]

I want to get rid of "Skolo Online ..." title and the description below it; however, I don't see that text in the "layout" template that's on GitHub.

How do I modify the the template in order to change that text or delete it entirely?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I opened the project on github and found that the text you are looking to delete is actually in the template/index.html file. The  that starts on line 8 and the closing tag  on line 15 contain the bodies of text you are looking to delete.